# why reactjs not getting cookies response from backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

When user enter correct username and password then my server sending jwt token response inside cookie.

See the **screenshot1** where I am getting cookie from my backend:

**screenshot1**
[image]

See the **screenshot2** where I am not getting any cookie from my backend to reactapp:

**screenshot2**
[image]

why I am not getting cookie response from my backend to reactjs app? I also tested my api on post man and getting cookie response. See the screenshot3

**screenshot3**
[image]

I am using axois post request:

`await axios.post(url, formdata,{withCredentials: true})`

**update1**
I am not providing any wrong login details in my react app. see the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to say that you are getting response where you are providing correct email and password but not getting any response when you are providing incorrect email and password? If so then we will need to look at the code. Maybe you have not handled errors correctly.

Comment: @Aravind Krishna I am not providing any wrong login details in my react app and also checking the response form my console so I am 100% sure I am login in my system but not getting any cookie data

Comment: Then I will have to check the code. Please add the code in a code sandbox and send the link.

Comment: It's simple post request. I added in my question.